# Mathematical notation for "in the domain of"

Tags: notation

Is there a mathematical symbol that lets me say something like "5 is in the domain of f" or "5 is NOT in the domain of f"?

Comment: Actually, even "domain of" would be useful. "5 in [symbol] f"

Answer (score 1):

$x \in \text{dom} \ f$, $x \notin \text{dom} \ f$

In your case, we'd have $x=5$.

Comment: I just used that as a simplified example. My actual problem is something like "$0 \text{ not in the domain of } x^{2}+1$" I think "$0 \notin \text{dom } x^2 +1$" should work quite well, unless you can't use the notation with an equation.

Comment: Well, $x^2 + 1$ is not a function. It's an expression. Talking about the domain of $x^2 + 1$ makes no sense.

Comment: I just realized I was looking for the wrong thing... Dangit. $\text{dom}$ will be handy in future, but I really need something for "0 not in the solution set of"... Also, I should be more careful with my wording. "Expression" and "equation" mean different things when speaking mathematically.

Comment: You answered this particular question quite nicely though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In computability theory the notation $f(x)\downarrow$ is often used for $x \in dom(f)$. The terminology that is used in this context is that the computation of $f(x)$ *converges*. The corresponding notation for $x \not \in dom(f)$ is $f(x) \uparrow$. I rather like this notation but it is seldom encountered outside of computability theory